# Windows authentication in MVC 3

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, authentication, iis-7, windows-authentication

I'm trying to set up Windows authentication in my web app, but I cannot make it work. The app run in my computer (Windows 7 x64), I am in a domain network, and the app is running on the real IIS, not the Cassini web server.

What I have done so far:

1. Enable basic authentication in IIS. (I have also tried to enable Windows Authentication)
2. Web.config `<authentication mode="Windows"></authentication>`
3. I have tried with and without `<identity impersonate="true"/>`
4. I have put the `AuthorizeAttribute` within my controllers.
5. I have tried also the `<add key="autoFormsAuthentication"
   value="false"/>` fix for MVC3 Beta.

What I got:

I can open the page that has no `AuthorizeAttribute`, I put a breakpoint and this is what I get in different properties related with authentication:

```
System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name
"IIS APPPOOL\\ASP.NET v4.0 DefaultAppPool"
Environment.UserDomainName
"IIS APPPOOL"
Environment.UserName
"ASP.NET v4.0 DefaultAppPool"
User.Identity.Name
""
```

Of course I cannot open any page with the `[Authorize]` attribute.

The only thing I want is get the Windows user name of the user that is accessing the web application. How should I do it?

Comment: Have you turned off "Anonymous" and "Forms" authentication in IIS?

Comment: You need to use ASP.NET impersonation.

Comment: can you create a new test project -> select mvc 3 web application -> select **Intranet** Application and see if that works?

Comment: Right, I have created a project from scratch and it works. I don't see the difference between both projects.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It worked after reboot the computer. No idea what was wrong.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, it got resolved after I added the following tag in my `<appSettings>` in my root `web.config`.

```
<add key="enableSimpleMembership" value="false"/>
```

along with this

```
<add key="autoFormsAuthentication" value="false"/>
```